# ssh-add works with id_ed25519 key but not with id_rsa key

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I have two keys in my `.ssh` folder, one is an `id_ed25519` key and the other an `id_rsa` key. If I run :

```
ssh-add ir_ed25519
```

I get the Identity added ... message and all is fine. If, on the other hand I try `ssh-add id_rsa`, it asks for a passphrase, I press enter since I have none (local project) and it returns me to the prompt. The server then rejects me with a `(public key) error`.

EDIT:

```
user@machine:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  config  google_compute_engine  google_compute_engine.pub  google_compute_known_hosts  id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
user@machine:~/.ssh$ ssh-add id_ed25519
Identity added: id_ed25519 (my_gitlab_key)
user@machine:~/.ssh$ ssh-add id_rsa
Enter passphrase for id_rsa: 
user@machine:~/.ssh$ 


user@machine:~/.ssh$ ssh -p 27 user@server_URL.com
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
user@server_URL.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The `id_rsa` key belongs to the server.

EDIT 2 :

```
user@computer:~/.ssh$ ssh -p 27 user@server-URL.com -v 
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server-URL.com [xxxxxxxxxx] port 27.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server-URL.com:27 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WCIqCPH...5A3dmWlf01g0m6k
debug1: Host '[server-URL.com]:27' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:HhRHqmr47/f0Lw+U3a+/a85ydnFvbns3KiQhKZbQC1Y /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:D+NWN6yffzHS...s6JiUWVjEU /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:iUFi29EEETE...Sv1Q6dhypY2o /home/user/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server-URL.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: paste complete command including error, get what exactly you are doing.

Comment: done, I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: This mean, destination doesn't approve your keys, more details you can get it with `-v` option while doing ssh.

Comment: also added the ssh -v results

Comment: not this `ssh -v 27 user@server-URL.com` like this `ssh -p 27 user@server-URL.com -v`, I am assuming your ssh port is 27. If it's mistake please remove `-p 27` and try

Comment: oh, sorry about that, yes, the port needs to be 27. I ran the correct command now

Comment: `debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server-URL.com: Permission denied (publickey).` mean your ssh key is either wrong or correct one is not loaded. Check with someone who having access on that server and match your public key.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't ask "Enter passphrase for key" unless the "id_rsa" was encrypted. It has a passphrase... don't just hit enter.

You can verify this with the `ssh-keygen` command. For example, to change your passphrase, use this command:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/filenamehere
```

If there is already a passphrase, it will ask for the old one, and after entering it, will ask for the new:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/filenamehere
Enter old passphrase: 
Key has comment 'examplecomment'
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

If not, it will only ask for the new one:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -~/.ssh/filenamehere
Key has comment 'examplecomment'
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```